# not accurate local time laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I use carbon to get the current local date and time by

```
$mytime = Carbon::now();
dd(var_dump($mytime->toDateTimeString()));
```

and I get this result

```
2015-11-21 13:20:05
```

and in my local time I have 9:20 PM (21:20 when 24hours format). Any ideas why time does not match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Carbon::now()` should give you the server's time zone, not the user's.

Check your `phpinfo()` and see if your time zone is set accurately.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/app.php` you may want to update this setting to match your location.

`'timezone' => 'UTC',`

Comment: its already in UTC, maybe its in my base phpinfo as @dtj mention

Answer (score 1):

You could check your `app/config.php` file... 
You have to change your

```
'timezone' => 'UTC'
```

to match your timezone..

Here is a list of timezone currently use in PHP..
Hope it helps...

[PHP Timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: its already in UTC, maybe its in my base phpinfo as @dtj mention